# tube punctures near valve

Tags: tire, rims, puncture

my road bike got a puncture in the front wheel yesterday while I was riding down a big slope, it happened when I was braking the bike then I heard a pop. I stopped and replaced with a new tube, resumed riding, and another pop when I was down a small slope, I remember I braked a bit as well. Two punctures appeared to be near the valve.
[image: two punctures near valve]

I found a hole in the tire, could it be the cause of two consecutive punctures?
[image]

Also found that side of the wire has a lot wear
[image]

while the other side of the wire has no wear at all
[image]

I checked the rim and its tape, didn't find any obvious spike or anything.

**Question 1: do I need to replace the tire?**

**Question 2: what causes the wear on one side of the tire?**

update: just found out the second tube I replaced, is a 650/18-25c tube, my rim is 700...

Comment: Looks to me like your brake pad may be rubbing the tire on one side and needs adjusting.

 Also always make sure you check your tire as well when changing a flat. A good method is to run your hand around the inside diameter of the whole tire. That way a sneaky thorn doesn't stay behind and pop your newly replaced tube.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that brake pad is touching your tire on the one side. Make it parallel to rim and/or move it a little bit down, if you don't same thing will happen to your new tire!
[image: Park tool manual example]
(via http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/linear-pull-brake-service)

Comment: thanks mocniak, as checked, the left front brake pad was bit high

Answer (score 5):

I would replace the tyre even if it's not the cause of the puncture as the bead is coming away. I'd do it reasonably quickly but I would take the risk of riding home or to the bike shop on it.

Do you know if this bit of the tyre was anywhere near the punctures? I put the manufacturer's logo next to the valve when I fit a tyre to make working this out easier.

By the way, tubes can take a lot of stretch. I've seen a 24" tube survive on a 26" wheel.

Comment: You should probably also check over the rim in case one side is rough/damaged/rusty.  Do you always park the bike in the same orientation relative to the prevailing weather?